# Java output in file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm a bit new to Java and running this program that asks me for a file name, reads the info in the file, uses it to fill an array and then asks me for the name of the file to put the output on.
However, when I ask for the file name for the output, it never reads it properly and I don't know why.
I'm using Scanners and this is how I have it coded now:

```
    System.out.println("What file name?");
    Scanner teclat = null;
    try {
        teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Wrong name!");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    String fitxer = teclat.toString();
    PrintWriter surtida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fitxer)); 
    teclat.close();
    String fitxer = teclat.next().trim();
```

And then I do the printing:

```
if(this.esBuit()) 
            System.err.println("Llista de llenguatges buida!");
        else {
            Node p = this.buscarNode(lleng);    // Busquem el Llenguatge  lleng  i imprimim tots els que han estat influenciats per aquest
            System.out.println("- - - - - - -\n");
            System.out.println("Llenguatges influenciats per "+lleng+":");
            while(p.inf != null) {
                System.out.print(p.inf.nom+"\n");
                    p = p.inf;
            }
            System.out.println("- - - - - - -");
        }
```

However, if I try to print the file name after the first block of code using `System.out.printnl` it prints a weird reference, as if it didn't read the file name properly.
How can I make it work?

EDITED: I updated the code i have and added a new issue that is possibly related:
I tried it and nothing changes. I'm trying something else, at the very beginning of the program, when I real the input file name, it reads the first line and does this:

```
String s = fitxer.toString();
        String b1 = s.substring(0,11);
        System.out.println(b1);
        String b2 = s.substring(0,14);
        System.out.println(b2);
```

And this prints:

```
java.util.S
java.util.Scan
```

Why?

Answer (score 3):

When you start reading from input:

```
String fitxer = teclat.toString();
```

should be

```
String fitxer = teclat.nextLine();
```

This is because [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#toString%28%29) converts the [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) object to a string representation. On the other hand [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) actually reads a line from the input that the scanner is pointing to.

It should be something like this:

```
System.out.println("What file name?");
Scanner teclat = null;
try {
    teclat = new Scanner(System.in);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Wrong name!");
    System.exit(-1);
}
String fitxer = teclat.nextLine();
PrintWriter surtida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fitxer)); 
teclat.close();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but a warning appears in the line `PrintWriter surtida = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fitxer));`, exactly at 'surtida', it tells me to add suppressWarning, any idea why it appears? I tried what you suggested and it shows me this error in the lane I changed: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` means that there was no input line, maybe it was an empty line?

Comment: The thing is, I can only enter the name of the file to read, then when it uses the info, some exceptions jump, and then it goes directly to this method, it prints the System.out.printnl but I can't type, it's like it reads something i haven't typed

Comment: Hmm, try using `teclat.next().trim()` instead of `teclat.nextLine()`.

Comment: I used it and nothing changed. I updated the code on the main question, I hope you can help me

Comment: You're still calling `toString` on the `Scanner`. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm using the code you put on your updated answer and it still happens the same. It doesn't let me put the name. It tells me this errors: `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
 at ConjuntLlenguatges.Mostrar(ConjuntLlenguatges.java:110)
 at Llenguatges.main(Llenguatges.java:56)` Line 110 is `String fitxer = teclat.nextLine();` Any idea?

Comment: Hmm, try replacing `teclat.nextLine()` with `teclat.next().trim()` again, otherwise I'm not sure what the problem could be.